# Where is the flaw in my algorithm to find the size of the largest subarray with each element within dista

Tags: c#, algorithm, sorting, time-complexity

For example, given the array `A={1,3,2,17,10}`, the answer is `3` because the collection `{1,2,3}` is the largest collection such that for some `a` in the collection, every element in the collection is the range `[a, a + 4]` (that's `a+4` inclusive).

My algorithm is like

```
    int[] toys = Array.ConvertAll(Console.ReadLine().Split(' '), Int32.Parse);
    Array.Sort(toys);
    int max_together = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < toys.Length; ++i)
    {
        int plus_four = toys[i] + 4;
        int j = i + 1;
        for(; j < toys.Length && toys[j] <= plus_four; ++j);
        int span = j - i;
        if(span > max_together)
        {
             max_together = span;               
        }
    }
```

and it's failing most of the test cases.

Or maybe I'm reading https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/priyanka-and-toys?h_r=next-challenge&h_v=zen incorrectly ...

My full solution is

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
class Solution
{
    static void Main(String[] args)
    {
        Console.ReadLine(); // N
        int[] toys = Array.ConvertAll(Console.ReadLine().Split(' '), Int32.Parse);
        Array.Sort(toys);
        int max_together = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < toys.Length; ++i)
        {
            int plus_four = toys[i] + 4;
            int j = i + 1;
            for(; j < toys.Length && toys[j] <= plus_four; ++j);
            int span = j - i;
            if(span > max_together)
            {
                 max_together = span;               
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine(1 + (toys.Length - max_together));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

On quick look i found that you are trying to find maximum span on sorted array(i.e.  1,2,3,10,17) whereas the test cases wants you to find the maximum span on given array(i.e. 1,3,2,17,10), the one before sorting.

Answer (score 0):

if you buy 1 toy whose weight is w1 ,you get all toys whose weight is in between [w1,w1+4] for free. The question asks you to find minimum number of toys you need to buy ,so that you get all toys in the input. In this example A={1,3,2,17,10}, the answer is 3  because you need to buy toy 1(or 2 or 3) ,17 and 10.

Java code

```
int num[] = {1,3,2,17,10};
 Arrays.sort(num);
        int result=1;
        int lastToy=num[0];
        for(int i=1;i<n;i++)
            {
            if(num[i] > lastToy+4)
                {
                result++;
                lastToy= num[i];
            }
        }
```